# Is conditional compilation bad practice when targeting .NET Standard and .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

I've always seen conditional compilation as bad practice unless you can't avoid it. AKA #ifdefhell See https://www.cqse.eu/en/news/blog/living-in-the-ifdef-hell/

I'm surprised that Microsoft seems to kind of encourage this without a comment or note that it ought to be avoided. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/libraries#how-to-multitarget

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
#if NET40
// This only compiles for the .NET Framework 4 targets
using System.Net;
#else
 // This compiles for all other targets
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
#endif
```

Should conditional compilation be avoided? Or is it perfectly acceptable to use? To me it's obvious, it's best avoided due to duplicated code, the difficulty in testing and complexity in maintain the code base. However having seen the Microsoft document it's made me question my own assertions.

Comment: Microsoft keeps on changing default options with each version of Net.  For example security class they use the latest/greatest encryption mode as the default.  So if you want backwards compatibility you may need to use a conditional compile.  Then when Microsoft went from Net 3.5 to Net 4.0 for SMTP in Net 4.0 you need to add DefaultCredentials which wasn't in Net 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you probably shouldn't multi-target in the first place, unless you're writing a library that will absolutely (not might, but absolutely!) be used to support legacy projects. Today, there is no reason not to write .Net5 code, unless you're writing UWP/Xamarin apps.

However, if you are multi-targetting, you need to write code that compiles under all your targets. That involves both `#if` and MsBuild targetted items, to conditionally include entire source code files.

Answer (score 1):

> I've always seen conditional compilation as bad practice **unless you can't avoid it**.

Exactly. Multi-targeting is one of those cases where it cannot be avoided.

The APIs between different versions and flavors of .NET are different, and therefore to do the same thing in a way that works across different targets you'll have to reference different assemblies and call the APIs that exist only in some assemblies but not in others.

In some cases you don't even have an alternative API and the conditional compilation will be used only to throw a `NotSupportedException` or similar.

Conditional compilation is crucial for multi-targeting both on the code itself, as well as within MSBuild scripts (for example, to decide which assemblies to reference):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.4;net40;net45</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Need to conditionally bring in references for the .NET Framework 4.0 target -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net40'">
    <Reference Include="System.Net" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Need to conditionally bring in references for the .NET Framework 4.5 target -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net45'">
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

---

That said, the further down the stack you can push the conditional compilation directives, the easier it is to maintain.

Creating (or using existing) abstractions that call the lower-level APIs, will help avoid conditional compilation directives all over the code of your app.